# Regex in batch script

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have file.txt where I have values in format:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Anyone have the idea to open such a file in a script and modify it to

```
'text1','text2','text3'
```

so far i have done it manually in notepad++ but i'd rather put it in some script just don't know how:

```
first step: 
find what: ^|$  
replace with: '
```

and

```
second step:
find what: [\r\n]+
replace with: ,
```

Comment: Batch hasn't any REGEX support (except the very crippled version in `findstr`, which isn't helpful here). When you don't want to switch to another language (for example PowerShell) and are willing to use a third-party tool, I recommend [jrepl](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Comment: it could be powershell, perl, python, but I don't know them. I would like to put such a script in the flow of the process

Comment: Your comment above, implies that you do know batch files; so where is the batch file code you want us to help you to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to convert a file with lines into a single-line file, where the single (original) lines are single-quoted and separated by a comma.

Not very efficient, but straightforward:

```
@echo off
set "infile=input.txt"
set "outfile=output.txt"
del "%outfile%" 2>nul
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%infile%") do (
  if not exist "%outfile%" (
    <nul set /p "='%%a'" > "%outfile%
  ) else (
    <nul set /p "=,'%%a'" >>"%outfile%"
  )
)
>>"%outfile%" echo(
type "%outfile%"
```

Take line by line, if it's the first line, write the quoted value, else write a comma plus the quoted value, both with the `<nul set /p` trick to write without a linefeed.